How to convert .dsr to .rpt files in VB.Net
I converted my VB6 project to VB.Net , but .dsr files are carry forwarded as it is without any changes. As .dsr files are not supported in VB.NET I want to migrate it .rpt or .rdlc files.
How can i do that convertion without any manual intervention? I didn't find the RPT file conversion feature in my VB6 Environment. Can someone help me out on this ?

If you open the .dsr file in the viewer (in VB6), don't you have the option to save it as .rpt?

Are you talking about Crystal Reports desginer file? See here: https://community.sap.com/t5/technology-q-a/crystal-reports-versions-and-dsr-files/qaq-p/10565216
